# Export/Import Url Rewrite Rules

Tags: magento-1.9, sql

We are on migration process, and need to migrate 5000 URL rewrite rules.

Could I do it via SQL? How?

Someone have a suggestion?

Comment: Is this from a Magento store to another Magento store?

Comment: Yes, I have to create a new magento store and made the import of the catálogo..customer and all, so I cant fins a way to bring the URL rewrite rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export the core_url_rewrite table with any SQL tool you have handy like phpMyAdmin and then reimport it in the other Magento store. 
Reindex and flush cache and all the rewrites should be there.